Nginx Refused to load the script
I have app running using nginx, but i have issue
firebase-messaging-sw.js:1 Refused to load the script 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.23.0/firebase-app-compat.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' googleapis.com gstatic.com jsdelivr.net". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
this is my nginx file
upstream svc_sftesting {
  ip_hash;
  server testing-develop.svc:3344 max_fails=2 fail_timeout=15s;
}

log_format apm '"$time_local" client=$remote_addr '
               'method=$request_method request="$request" '
               'request_length=$request_length '
               'status=$status bytes_sent=$bytes_sent '
               'upstream_addr=$upstream_addr '
               'upstream_status=$upstream_status '
               'request_time=$request_time '
               'upstream_response_time=$upstream_response_time '
               'upstream_connect_time=$upstream_connect_time '
               'upstream_header_time=$upstream_header_time';

server {
  listen 3000;
  server_name testing.com;


  add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
  add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
  add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
  add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";

  # Header Content Security Policy
  add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' googleapis.com gstatic.com jsdelivr.net; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://www.gstatic.com https://www.googleapis.com; script-src-elem 'self' https://www.gstatic.com; connect-src 'self' https://fcm.googleapis.com https://www.googleapis.com; worker-src 'self' blob: https://www.gstatic.com https://www.googleapis.com;" always;

  add_header Referrer-Policy "origin-when-cross-origin" always;
  add_header Feature-Policy "camera 'none'; geolocation 'none'; microphone 'none'; payment 'none'; usb 'none'" always;

  server_tokens off;
  add_header Server "Hidden" always;
  proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;

  error_page 400 403 404 500 502 503 504 /error.html;

  location = /error.html {
    internal;
    root /app;
  }

  client_max_body_size 100M;
  root /app;
  index index.html;

  access_log /dev/stdout apm;
  error_log /dev/stderr;

  location /nginx_status {
    stub_status on;
    access_log off;
    allow all;
  }

  location = /robots.txt {
    return 301 http://$host;
  }

  location / {
    add_header Set-Cookie "Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict";
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }

  location /firebase-messaging-sw.js {
    alias /app/public/firebase-messaging-sw.js;  
    default_type "application/javascript";
    add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://www.gstatic.com https://www.googleapis.com; worker-src 'self' blob: https://www.gstatic.com;" always; 
    try_files $uri =404;
  }

  location /services/ {
    proxy_cache_revalidate on;
    proxy_cache_min_uses 3;
    proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout updating http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    proxy_cache_background_update on;
    proxy_cache_lock on;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
    proxy_read_timeout 5400s;
    proxy_send_timeout 5400s;

    proxy_cookie_path / "/; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Strict";

    proxy_pass http://svc_sftesting/;
  }
}



The error message in your question does not match your Nginx config file. There is no CSP directive containing default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' googleapis.com gstatic.com jsdelivr.net. Check the Nginx error log and access log for the exact URL being accessed. Use sudo nginx -T to view the entire Nginx configuration. Always restart Nginx after making a change to its configuration.

error message is when i inspect the page of app

The "problem" is your Header Content Security Policy
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' googleapis.com gstatic.com jsdelivr.net; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://www.gstatic.com https://www.googleapis.com; script-src-elem 'self' https://www.gstatic.com; connect-src 'self' https://fcm.googleapis.com https://www.googleapis.com; worker-src 'self' blob: https://www.gstatic.com https://www.googleapis.com;" always;

try allowing "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.23.0/firebase-app-compat.js":
add_header Content-Security-Policy "default-src 'self' googleapis.com gstatic.com jsdelivr.net; 
script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://www.gstatic.com https://www.googleapis.com https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.23.0/firebase-app-compat.js; 
script-src-elem 'self' https://www.gstatic.com https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.23.0/firebase-app-compat.js; 
connect-src 'self' https://fcm.googleapis.com https://www.googleapis.com; 
worker-src 'self' blob: https://www.gstatic.com https://www.googleapis.com;" always;


still got the same error. i was update the same configuration like yours

Try commenting out that line in the Nginx configuration, meaning temporarily remove the header to see if there's any difference in the application's behavior.
